# Cannot call method 'getSouthWest' of undefined when visualizing an address

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I am trying to display a marker for an address that the user enters in a web form. The problem is that I am getting the following error

> Cannot call method 'getSouthWest' of undefined

when I try to show the marker using the following code:

```
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                //Remove all markers from the map
            clearMarkers();

                //Display the new marker on the map
            showFullAddressesOnMap(latitude, longitude, address);

            //Center the map according to the marker
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);                      
        }
    });

function showFullAddressesOnMap(latitude, longitude, fullAddress) {
    displayMarker(-1, "", "", "", fullAddress, true, latitude, longitude);
}

function displayMarker(appID, title, image, imageType, address, markerType, lat, lng) {

    var listingLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: listingLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: markerType ? imgBluePin : imgGreenPin,
        title: title + address
    });

    var content = GetContent(appID, title, image, imageType, address);

    marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content,
        size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        closeAllWindows();
        marker.info.open(map, marker);
    }); 

    bounds.extend(listingLatLng);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Also, the error does not happen every time. Here is an address that crashes the code.

> France, Ile-de-France, Paris, 75006, Paris, 7 rue casimir delavigne

I think the error is caused when `FitBounds` is called. When the error happens the bounds that are returned by the geocoding is zoomed out to Province level.

What is the cause of the error? I need to zoom the map to street level when the user enters address with street name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bounds isn't defined somewhere.

You must define it in a scope where it is accessible by displayMarker, before you use it's methods or use it as argument for methods:

```
bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Comment: but why does geocode return no bounds. Moreover, why it happens from time to time?

Comment: You cannot trust on bounds returned by geocoding, they will be returned "if applicable" , as you can read in the docs. The address you've used will return an exact point, a street-number, so there is no area that can have any bounds.

Comment: Yes, geocoding returns "undefined" for the bounds. This happens when I add the street name and number, but if I just type "France, Paris, 75006" it is ok. Why it cannot find the bounds although it finds the full address even with the street name and number?

Comment: Bounds define an area, a point (that's what an adress with a street-number is) doesn't have an area

Comment: Thanks. Your comments helped me a lot. I thought that geocoding always return bounds.